# php code in FTP to backup db using URL

Tags: php, ftp, backup

I fund and inserted this code in my FTP in a backup.php that works great but 
it copy the file into the root folder (homez/)

1- I would like to put these backup files in a homez/backupDB any idea where to put this path?

2- the db backup files (DB.sql.bz2) have always the same name, is it possible to name each one with the date of creation? (I launch this php with the URL link)

```
<?
echo "Votre base est en cours de sauvegarde.......

";
$db="nom_de_ma_base";
$status=system("mysqldump --host=mysql5-1.perso --user=$_POST[login] --password=$_POST[password] $db > ../$db.sql");
echo $status;
echo "Compression du fichier.....

";
system("bzip2 -f ../$db.sql");
echo "C'est fini. Vous pouvez récupérer la base par FTP
\n
";
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `../$db.sql` is the part saving the file to a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
echo "Votre base est en cours de sauvegarde.......

";
$db="nom_de_ma_base";
$status=system("mysqldump --host=mysql5-1.perso --user=$_POST[login] --password=$_POST[password] $db > ../$db.sql");
echo $status;
echo "Compression du fichier.....

";
system("bzip2 -f /homez/backupDB/$db" . date("d-M-Y", time()) . ".sql");
echo "C'est fini. Vous pouvez récupérer la base par FTP
\n
";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much : it works -> incredible! Have a good day!